# How to use scp between servers

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

I have 2 Linux machines (CentOS), and I want to transfer a file from one of them to a directory on the other. A co-worker suggested using scp. I've looked at the official docs, and tried getting it to work to no avail.

Server names are thing1.me.org and thing2.me.org; if I am on thing1, and want to SSH into thing2, I just type the following command, and I'm in.

```
 ssh thing2.me.org
```

I tried doing the same for SCP, and had no luck. I tried all sorts of variants, but I'm getting nowhere.

```
scp myfile.txt thing2.me.org/opt/app/
scp myfile.txt ssh://thing2.me.org/opt/app
```

Do you have any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scp syntax is host:file, so you want

```
scp myfile.txt thing2.me.org:/opt/app/
```

(If the target path is empty does not start with a `/`, it will be relative to your home directory.)

Comment: You can also do it completely without sshing into thing1 at all. `scp thing1.me.org:/path/to/myfile.txt thing2.me.org:/opt/app/`